# Speaker sound does not play when set with Python

Tags: python, scripting, audio

I am trying to import and set the sound of a freshly created speaker using Python. Strangely the sound plays normally when I import it manually, but when I use Python to do the same thing it does not. Even when imported via script, the sound still shows up normally in the speaker-menu.
This is my code:

```
bpy.ops.object.speaker_add()
bpy.ops.sound.open_mono(filepath=my_file_path)
bpy.data.speakers["Speaker"].sound = bpy.data.sounds[os.path.basename(path)]
```

I have made sure my file path is correct.

Comment: Good question! When adding the speaker using the add menu, Blender adds a NLA Track as well. However, I'm not sure why there is no option to set that up automatically.

Comment: Actually it adds an NLA track in - and I've also tried to delete that and add one in manually but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

If `my_file_path` is a relative path, use the absolute file path instead.

Be aware that `bpy.ops.sound.open_mono` gives no warning or error message even if the audio file is not found (or does not exist). The sound still shows up normally in the speaker-menu but you can't hear anything.

I also had to call `update_tag()` and relink the speaker to the collection. I have no clue why this is necessary, but the following code works in Blender 2.83:

```
my_file_path = "/absoulute/path/to/test.mp3"
bpy.ops.object.speaker_add()
speaker = bpy.context.object
speaker.data.sound = bpy.data.sounds.load(my_file_path)
speaker.data.update_tag()
bpy.context.collection.objects.unlink(speaker)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(speaker)
```